# How to show line number and column number in status bar in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, statusbar

I want to add row and column number in status bar, but I don't understand how to add. Please help me, how to show line number and column number in Python Tkinter status bar.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Testing 6.py")
root.geometry('500x500')

StatusBar = Frame(root, width=10, borderwidth=1, relief=SUNKEN)
StatusBar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
StatusBarlabel = Label(StatusBar, text='My Notepad')
StatusBarlabel.pack(side=LEFT)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to show where the cursor is currently in the text widget (row:column) so here is a minimal example on how to do that:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Text, Label


def update_label():
    row, col = text.index('insert').split('.')
    label.config(text=f'{row}:{col}')
    root.after(100, update_label)


root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

label = Label(root, anchor='e')
label.pack(fill='x')
update_label()

root.mainloop()
```

Basically simply have a loop that will constantly get the current index using the `.index` method and value of `"insert"` which returns the index of where currently the cursor is, then loop and config the text of a label to show this to the user.

Sources:

- [`Text` widget `.index` method (you will have to find it between the others tho)](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-methods.html)
- [`Text` widget indicies](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html)

Comment: Thanks for Helping me i am realy appreciate you work once again thanks a lot.

Comment: @SyedAhsan9682 please see [What to do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will help future readers and also allow to mark other questions as duplicates.